# python 2.7 __init__ behavior on self

Tags: python, initialization

I have a python question that I'm sure is pretty simple - please feel free to disabuse me of any sort of bad practice while you're at it. I have the following code:

```
class User(dict,BaseDBI):
    def __init__(self,uid=None,username=None):
        self['uid']=str(uuid())     
        if uid == None and username is not None:            
            uid_struct = self.Get('data/username.kch',username)         
            if uid_struct is not None:
                self = self.Get('data/user.kch',uid_struct['uid'])
```

As you can tell this User is simply an extended dict object. It also accesses a few simple Get and Set methods on a couple of Kyoto Cabinet db files. I put in some print statements to trace through what's going on and everything is being set properly, but when I create a User object (e.g.):

```
user = User(username='someusername')
```

and then print user I only have a new dict object that has the brand new `uid` generated by the first line under `__init__`

Thanks for any wisdom!

Comment: why does it inherit from dict anyways? Are you sure you don't want to call the base classes `__init__` too? Sure you get a `dict`, it should be a object that just *looks* like a dict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python variables are references. when you assign to `self`, you are replacing that reference but not altering the object which is returned by `__init__`.

The easiest thing may be to simply use the dict.update method to copy all key/value pairs into `self`. This should 'just work' since you're already inheriting from dict.

Inheritance is only appropriate for a relationship like `A is a B`. You indicate that a User is a dict, that's fine, but I doubt that a User is a BaseDBI. It's more likely that you want a User to *have* a database, in which case composition is more appropriate. This probably seems nit-picky, but will prevent you from making bizarre and obscene systems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Also, thank you for the composition suggestion - it's better to get that feedback now than later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the inherited constructors. Something like:

```
def __init__(self,uid=None,username=None):
    dict.__init__(self)
    BaseDBI.__init__(self)
```

Also assigning to `self` will just replace the value in the local variable `self`. It will not have any effect on the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return an already existing instance or your class, you need to define a `__new__` method

By the time `__init__` is called, a fresh instance has already been created

Comment: Thanks. This will always be a fresh instance, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @swasheck, ahh, looks like you didn't really mean to be rebinding self